# Why does Cargo not Work on Emulated Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, rust

When I was trying to install rust on this Linux machine, it worked (though it did say the `$HOME is not the same as euid derived home`).  I ran the script again (the standard rustup.sh script), this time using `-y`, and it installed just fine.  But when I tried to make a new project, and run it, it claimed that it was not able to find `Cargo.toml` even though it was in the correct directory.

Screenshot:

[image: Screen capture of the terminal]

Things of Note:

1. The root is simulated using `proot`
2. I did run `source "$HOME/.cargo/env"`
3. The euid-derived home is `/root`
4. I did not use `sudo` during the install
5. Regular `rustc` works when compiling the source
6. When I direct it to the exact path of `Cargo.toml`, it says that it cannot find the target directory.
7. `strace` dose not work on this machine.